# Replacing a Gtk Submenu with another

Tags: python, gtk

I have a submenu in my application that needs to change based on information downloaded from the internet (at runtime). My current code:

```
def rebuild_asset_menu(self):
    self.exchange_menu.set_submenu(self._menu_exchange()) # returns a GtkMenu
    self.exchange_menu.show_all()

def _menu_exchange(self):
    exchange_list_menu = Gtk.Menu()
    self.exchange_group = []
    subgroup = [] # group all asset pairs of all exchange menus together
    for exchange in self.coin.EXCHANGES:
        item = Gtk.RadioMenuItem.new_with_label(self.exchange_group, exchange.get('name'))
        item.set_submenu(self._menu_asset_pairs(exchange, subgroup))
        item.connect('toggled', self._handle_toggle, exchange.get('code'))
        self.exchange_group.append(item)
        exchange_list_menu.append(item)

        if self.active_exchange == exchange.get('code'):
            item.set_active(True)

    return exchange_list_menu
```

Unfortunately, this inconsistently yielded core dumps, segfaults and "double free or corruption (fasttop)" errors. To be fair, I'm not sure if this is what causes those errors, but it's my best guess. I can't make anything out of those hex addresses from the core dump.

I have also tried removing the old submenu first before attaching a new submenu, with `self.exchange_menu.remove(self.exchange_menu.get_submenu())`. But that gave the following error:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_remove: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == GTK_WIDGET (container) || GTK_IS_ASSISTANT (container) || GTK_IS_ACTION_BAR (container) || GTK_IS_POPOVER_MENU (container)' failed

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: in fact I just realised it may be because I should call that function using `GLib.idle_add()`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's too difficult to try and reproduce your error if we have to guess what your menu looks like.

Comment: updated it with a bit more info about the submenu being attached. But I really think it was solved with `idle_add()`.

Comment: that said I'd like to know how to properly use `remove()` without receiving that Gtk-CRITICAL error.